# Ratio, Root, and Comparison Tests

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble figuring out the limits. What messes me up is that the limit approaches infinity. Usually it approaches a specific number. Is that a trick to solve problems like these?

So for example, use the root test to find convergence/divergence. (n!)^n/(n^n)^7. n=1 and it's to infinity

Comment: Could you be more specific? For example, write a question you're having problems with because limits is a very broad topic

Comment: Just added an example!

Comment: refer to solution for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

${\root n\of{a_n}}=n!/n^7\to\infty$, so $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: But I don't understand how you get to that answer.. Can you please explain?

Comment: $n!/n^7\to\infty$ because $n!$ increases faster than any fixed power of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}=\dfrac{(n!)^n}{(n^n)^7}$$
so,we let $a_n=\dfrac{(n!)^n}{(n^n)^7}.$

To use the root test,we take 
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|}$$
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{(n!)^n}{(n^n)^7}}$$
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{(n!)}{(n)^7}$$
And as n! increases much faser than $n^7$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$
$$L=\infty$$
As $L\ne0$, The series diverges.